# Is dancing at a club or rave forbidden?

Tags: halacha

Is dancing at a rave not for the purposes of mingling with another sex forbidden? The background is that there are many different venues with different music , different personalities and different objectives. Not all clubs are hotspots for douchey guys with sports cars coming in with a girl in a red dress. There are venues that instead attract people who just want to dance and enjoy themselves, enjoy the music, like Uman on Rosh Hashana except it’s mixed gender, with sometimes people of unknown gender. I know there is the existent question on mixed dancing but it doesn’t address this particular situation. I want to know if there are blanket prohibitions of even entering into and dancing in such venues where the goal is not at all for the other sex and is in fact for the purpose of expanding the mind and soul and even bringing Torah to the outer world.

Comment: Are you asking for a Jew or for a non-Jew?

Comment: Dancing at a club to bring Torah to the world???

Comment: also relevant: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/99178/what-are-the-practical-parameters-of-mitzvah-habaah-baveirah/99221#99221